# When I delete my iOS application push notification state remains

Tags: ios, xcode, uninstallation

When I install my iOS application using Xcode for the first time, my iPhone asks whether I want to enable push notifications.

I am able to send a notification, and the badge shows a number that I sent.

When I delete the application from my iPhone and rebuild it in Xcode and reinstall it again on my iPhone (using Xcode):

- The device does not ask if I want to enable push.
- The badge is there and **remembers** the last number.

I tried the same application on a fresh device (installed the IPA) and it asked me for permissions.

How can I completely make my device forget the application?

Comment: @KananVora are you sure you copied the right question ?

Comment: Sorry it was pasted here by mistake...

Comment: Well, the installation process of Xcode and Appstore must be different, you are better to conduct preproduction tests agains the Release .ipa as said at Apple guidelines. The question i have - are you registering the app for notifications every time the app is launched ?

Comment: @A-Live it's a pain to create an ipa, copy it to the device, everytime i make a slight change to my application, isn't there another whay? also i guess i do register every time, according to the logs on Xcode (i log the device number).

Comment: I've not seen such behavior before, if that is iOs 6 preview you might want to address the question to Apple forums. The only advice i could give is to try to remove the app from Organizer - Devices - particular-device-Applications.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a workaround for this that involves setting the system time ahead by two days, rebooting the device, and then changing the system time back to the present. iOS is designed to only ask permission for push once a day per application.

> Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS The first
>   time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the
>   user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user
>   has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the
>   device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or
>   more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back
>   on.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: I made my device timing two days ahead and then restarted but not working . I am using iPhone 5 .

Comment: Check below for iOS 5.1+ answer

Comment: To simulate the first run of the app.. you can just change the bundle identifier and launch the app... Just a simple fix..

Answer (score 38):

Updated for iOS 7 and later from Apple's docs:

> On iOS 7 and later, The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

For iOS 5 and iOS6:

> Reset the push notifications permissions alert by restoring the device from a backup (r. 11450187). Here are the steps to do this efficiently:
>
> 1. Use the Xcode Organizer to install your app on the device. The key is to install the app for the first time without running it.
> 2. Use iTunes to back up the device.
> 3. Run the app. The push notifications permissions alert will be presented.
> 4. When you want to reset the push notifications permissions alert, restore the device from the backup you created in the first step.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: This worked for me (iOS 7, XCode 5). In my case, the catch was that I disallowed push notifications initially. After that, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken _nor_ didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError was called. When following the steps above you're able to enable them again.

Comment: Unbelievable Apple - make a shortcut for your developers!

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same boat you were. What I found most helpful was to slightly change the bundle identifier.

Example:
Your bundle identifier is com.company.app. If you need to test enabling push notifications change the identifier to com.company.app1. It will install as a new app and have new push notification permission settings.

Just make sure to change it back when you're done testing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no relation in that `iOS` remember `push settings,badge` value and you are not getting `push notification`. I am sure that there is some other issue. Yes, `iOS` remembers `push settings` and `badge` value for an app. It asks for push confirmation when you first install on device . You can reset `badge` value by calling `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:`

if you want to reset `push settings` then you can do it by reset all `setting` of your device.

Comment: Absolutely. I just received a notification I sent yesterday (after I posted the question) !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any app initialization code (eg., copying/initializing db when there are no db available in documents folder. so you know it is reinstalled) you could reset the badge count to zero.

Again, this could fail if the users are manually deleting the db file from package or if you dont have such initialize setup for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following Steps to stimulate First time run of your app by these steps:

1). Delete your app from the device.

2). Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.

3). Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.

4). Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.