# Can you mute incoming Push Notifications from the App side [iOS]

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mute

I am making an app that uses Apples Push Notifications. I want to be able to have an "off duty" mode, in which the push notification is still received, but no sound is played when it comes in. Is there a way to mute these push notifications from inside the app? I know I can simply not send the sound from the JSON message, but it would be easier if I could do it from inside the app. I want to still receive the notifications, so I don't want to unregister from push notifications

Comment: Have a look at the below post: [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: You could register for the type `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` or not, depending on your "duty"-status. However, that way I think you will have to send all notifications  twice - once with sound, once witout - and I am not even sure that would work the way I am just envisioning :D.

Answer (score 5):

If your app is in background, the only way to mute the push is not send the sound from the JSON message.

When your app is foreground, you will receive push by application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, in this case, whether your send sound or not, app will receive push silently.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the registration to not include sound.

When you want to sound the notifications, call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

When you want to mute the notifications:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

This will allow only the alert and badge to be displayed. The sound won't be played.

EDIT:

I believe the following [quote](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)  implies that the notification won't be filtered if the payload contains a type that is not enabled. The device simply won't display/sound the type that is not enabled.

> The system does not badge icons, display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these notifications types are not enabled for your app, even if they are specified in the notification payload.

You should also note that whatever types of notifications your app chooses to enable/disable, the users can override that decision manually:

> Users can modify the enabled notification types at any point, using Settings in iOS or System Preferences in OS X.

Comment: Wouldnt that filter out any notifications that are bundled with sounds alltogether? In other words, once registered for notifications without sound only (your 2nd example); would a notification that was sent with sound be entirely ignored?

Comment: Do I have to un-register remote notifications before I can call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes again? Also does it ask the user if they want to be sent push notifications everytime you call that function? Also Till brings up a good point

Comment: @Till I believe it wouldn't filter out the notifications that has sound, but I haven't tested it. It's worth trying.

Comment: @Eran indeed, worth a shot.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure if you'll have to un-register before registering again (you'll have to try and find out), but I'm sure that the user won't be asked again to allow push notifications (since they are asked only the first time the app calls that method).

Comment: So even though this answer seems right, I still get sounds after I register for only badges. Does apple have to process the registration, and maybe it's not immediate? That's the only reasoning I could think of. I've tried with and without unregistering first.

Comment: @Kevin, that's strange. Did you try to register from the start without sound, and then see if the sound plays in this case? I'd also suggest that you check the notification options of your application (whether sound is enabled or disabled) before and after you register for only badges.

Comment: @Eran I uninstalled the App completely, and set it to `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` , but when I went into the settings App and went under notifications, it says that it's registered for Badges, Sounds, and Banners. It seems like no matter what I do, it's always registered for those three things, even if I call `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`

Comment: @Kevin Perhaps they changed the behavior is later iOS versions. I tested it last year and I remember at some point I didn't get an alert notification, and later discovered I forgot to register for alert notification type.

Comment: @Eran according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369900/when-i-delete-my-ios-application-push-notification-state-remains APNS only asks for notification permissions once a day, which would explain why it is remaining the same after deletion. If this is the case, then I assume that I can only change the Notification Type once a day.

Comment: @Kevin I thought that once a day thing was only relevant for the alert you get upon first launch of the app.