# Check if iOS push notifications status is not determined

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m prompting my user to enable push notifications after the user logs in to my app. I know how to test if push notifications are enabled or disabled using:

```
isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

and it works just fine. It returns YES for enabled and NO for not available but I want to be able to figure out how to check for Not Determined (the user wasn’t prompted to enable push notifications to begin with). Is there a way to test that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You create `Not Determined` state yourself.

```
func registerNotification() {
    // 1.Call register API
    // ...

    // 2.Save a bool value to indicate you've called this method or not.
    let appleSuggestedUserDefaultsKeyPrefix = "com.yourcompany.product-"
    let key = appleSuggestedUserDefaultsKeyPrefix + "didCallRegisterNotificationAPI"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: key)
}
```

And in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method you need check if you have called `registerNotification()`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let didCallRegisterNotificationAPI = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(...)
    if didCallRegisterNotificationAPI {
        // If registered or user denied, call this method will NOT show the alert. 
        // Just the same as you did before.
        registerNotification()
    } else {
        print("registerNotification() has not been called")
    }
}
```

And finally you can call `registerNotification()` directly anywhere anytime as you need and the alert is under your control now.

Comment: I tried all possible solutions from iOS but none of them work, in the end I have to implement that my myself, for now at least.

Answer (score 2):

`isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is a `Bool`.  There is no undetermined status.  You can verify this is the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications).

When the user first installs your app they must either allow or disallow push notifications.  There is no other possible option.

However, maybe you're asking because you can delete the app, reinstall, and it won't ask you for permission.  That's because the permission is remembered.

> Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS
>   The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

Delete your app from the device.
Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG21)

Associated Question: [When I delete my iOS application push notification state remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369900/when-i-delete-my-ios-application-push-notification-state-remains)

**EDIT:**

You can only use `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` to check that they are simply not registered, whether that's due to declining or due to you never trying to register.

However, as long as you try to register in a valid way (valid certs and profiles etc) and the user declines, your app will call did register, but with nil `UIUserNotificationSettings`:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    if notificationSettings.types == nil {
        println("You didn't allow notifcations")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I wasn’t asking because I’m trying to delete the app.

In my case, I registered for remote notifications after the users log in (not on startup) so there is a case that the notifications status will be undetermined.

I guess a better way to ask this will be: is there a to detect if the user rejected push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of UNNotificationSettings's authorizationStatus property.

```
private func checkNotificationsAuthorizationStatus() {
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { notificationSettings in
        switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("Authorized to schedule or receive notifications.")
        case .denied:
            print("Not authorized to schedule or receive notifications.")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined whether the app is allowed to schedule notifications.")
        case .provisional: // Available from iOS 12.0
            print("Provisionally authorized to post noninterruptive user notifications.")
        @unknown default:
            print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    self.checkNotificationsAuthorizationStatus()
    return true
}
```